# How to cleanup/teardown provided objects inside a Module

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have a custom Dagger Scope.

```java
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FeatureScope {
}
```

I have a Component/Module that provides a Presenter (any UI element will really work here) that is tied to this scope.

```java
@FeatureScope
@Component(modules = {
        CustomScopedModule.class
})
public interface CustomScopedComponent {

}
```

```java
@Module
public class CustomScopedModule {

    @FeatureScope
    @Provides
    Presenter providePresenter() {
        return new Presenter();
    }
}
```

I know that it is up to me to create/destroy this custom scope when it is no longer needed. So in my application I have:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private CustomScopedComponent customScopedComponent;

    public CustomScopedComponent getCustomScopedComponent() {
        if (customScopedComponent == null) {

            customScopedComponent = DaggerCustomScopedComponent.builder()
                    .contactsModule(new CustomScopedModule())
                    .build();
        }
        return customScopedComponent;
    }

    public void finishedWithCustomScopedComponent() {
        customScopedComponent = null;
    }
```

However I now need to "cleanup" after taking Component (and Presenter) out of scope. I can't just set customScopedComponent to null. I also need to call cleanup() on my `Presenter`:

```java
class Presenter {

    public void cleanup() {
        // Dispose of all the things
        // Release any DB connections
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to handle/create a call path to handle this? I see that Dagger doesn't really have any tools for this and that I need to roll my own solution [Discussion](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/238#issuecomment-155321987)

So I thought at least I could add a method to the module:

```java
@Module
public class CustomScopedModule {

    @FeatureScope
    @Provides
    Presenter providePresenter() {
        return new Presenter();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        // call Presenter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

And call it when destroying the component:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private CustomScopedComponent customScopedComponent;
    private CustomScopedModule customScopedModule;

   ...

    public void finishedWithCustomScopedComponent() {
        customScopedModule.cleanup();
        customScopedComponent = null;
    }
}
```

But my question is, how can the module's `cleanup()` method get access to the presenter? Only thing I can think of is just saving the presenter as a field inside the module:

```java
@Module
public class CustomScopedModule {

    private Presenter presenter;

    @FeatureScope
    @Provides
    Presenter providePresenter() {
        presenter = new Presenter(); // save instance to cleanup later
        return presenter;
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        if (presenter != null) {
            presenter.cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems ugly and very un-Dagger to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to get the presenter from the component by adding `fun getPresenter(): Presenter` and then just before making the component null, you just call the cleanup method of the presenter?

Comment: That could work. My application though would then have to know what needs to be cleaned up. Which is still kind of ugly. I'd also then expose the presenter from the object graph which doesn't encapsulate very well.

Comment: Another option perhaps is to make the presenter lifecycle aware and cleanup when needed

Comment: Sadly we're moving to custom scopes precisely because we don't want to tie presenter to fragtivity lifecycle. We want our presenters to outlive the fragtivity they work with.